# how to get active file address in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to get the path of current selected file in eclipse. My project is a simple view plugin project. I just want to display the name/path of the file selected as soon as user opens the view.

Comment: Each view / editor has its own selection. So which selection do you want?